# NHibernate internal data-retrieval method

Tags: nhibernate, data-retrieval

Internally, does NHibernate use DataSets or SqlDataReaders to access data from sql server or does it depend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses neither, actually. What it uses is an "abstract" [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx), for which there are several platform-dependent implementations. For SQL Server it does use `SqlDataReader`, yes.

In NHibernate, there's a notion of an `IDriver`, which provides and abstraction for core NHibernate code and is responsible for creation of platform-specific instances of `IDbConnection` and `IDbCommand` objects.

Comment: Well, this abstract IDbDataReader will contain a SqlDataReader when NHibernate accesses a SQL Server DB.  (This is what Mr Grok asked ' ... to access data from sql server ...')

Comment: Good, I just didn't want to see it use datasets etc in the background because they're too slow for asp.net dev for me.  And it doesn't - excellent... Thanks.